# Appium driver to get app package name programmatically

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I am using:

```
appiumDriver.findElement(By.id("com.XXX.keyword:id/nextButton"));
```

but sometimes we have debug version, so we have something like "com.XXX.keyword.debug". So I want to get package name before test runs so the tests can be independent on this.

I tried

```
driver.currentActivity()
```

but it only returned something like ".MainActivity"

Is there any way to get package name with Appium?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4609

Comment: Why are you using package name and id together ? Use only 'nextButton'.

Comment: @ShekharSwami, oh man, you saved my day. I used Appium Inspector, and saw that attribute : resource_id="com.XXX.keyword:id/nextButton", then I assumed that is complete id value. Thanks a lot. If you can write it as an answer, I am gonna accept it.

Comment: Okay.. will do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need package name to locate elements. Simply copy paste id without package name . eg in your case use only '`nextButton`' instead of '`com.XXX.keyword:id/nextButton`'

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with `elementByIdOrNull()`? I need to pass the full package name and ":id/" for it to find the element.

Comment: This is true in many cases but sometimes, like with `elementByIdOrNull` and when using XPaths, you need to provide the full package name and ":id/". For those cases, see @RajKumar's answer.

Comment: it works only if we are using findelement by id. But if we need to use the id in XPath then we need to use complete id.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current package name use following method:

```
driver.getCurrentPackage();
```

The following statement you are using will give you Activity Name.

```
driver.currentActivity();
```

Comment: Method has not yet been implemented